# Django: how to change table names globally?

Tags: python, django

I know I can change table name per model using `db_table` attribute, as explained [in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#db-table).

However, what if I want to do it globally? Let's say, I want all my table to be like:

```py
db_table = f"table_{{model_name}}"
```

Is there any setting for this?
Otherwise, I guess I could use a mixin to be inherited from. However, the whole purpose of doing this is to NOT think of table naming when any developer will add a new model.

After reading [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/891), It seems maintainers didn't even consider to add this feature as they did not understand the need, which is pretty clear to me :/

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You could quite easily create a custom BaseModel to handle this, with whatever decision making you require, however I agree with the core devs, I don't see how this adds direct value. Are you perhaps sharing the database schema with other applications?

Comment: The value is simple: when it's a setting, it's set one and for all. You don't even need to think of inheriting from the base model you would have defined. Hence, you lower the risk to make an error, especially when new developers join the team. Absurd counter example: would you be ok to define `LANGUAGE_CODE` value for each view you write (even with inheritance) ?

Comment: This discussion will only lead to opinions, which are better suited for the django mailing list

Comment: I agree it can be an opinion to prefer using a way to do this on every model. However I think it's factual that a "once for all" setting has different implications that a "do it each time" setting.

Answer (score 0):

The default database table naming goes like `db_table = f"{app_label}_{model_name}"` and you can rewrite them As [hedde-van-der-heide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911519/hedde-van-der-heide) suggested, by creating an abstract base model and subclassing them on your models, like

```
from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = f"table_{model_name}"


class NewModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: How do you get the actual `model_name` value?

Comment: ```{model_name}``` is one of the possible metadata options that are available in model meta class which refers to the model class name. just by using ```{model_name}```, you will get the model class name

Comment: did you try the code you wrote? For me, with the `f` string, model_name is undefined. Except if I missed something, without the `f`, this code has no effect at all.